# Aggregate json data in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to pyspark , Can anyone please help me in aggregating this data.

I have json data in a text file like this

```
{"a":1 , "b":"abc", "c":"abc2", "d":"abc3" , "e":"1234"}
{"a":1 , "b":"abc2", "c":"abc", "d":"abc" ,"e":"1234"}
{"a":1 , "b":"abc", "c":"abc2", "d":"abc3","e":"123"}
```

I want to aggregate data on 'b','c','d'columns while adding values in column 'a' and then adding a new column 'unique_e' which will give unique 'e' column valuess on the basis of column 'e'.

This is the final output that i want

```
{"a":2 , "b":"abc", "c":"abc2", "d":"abc3" , "unique_e":"2"}
{"a":1 , "b":"abc2", "c":"abc", "d":"abc" , "unique_e":"1"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
 df = spark.read.json(pathToFile)
 df2 = df.groupby("b","c","d").agg(f.countDistinct(df["e"]).alias("unique_e"), f.sum(df["a"]).alias("sum_a"))
```

if you want to save this to a single json file you can do:

```
df2.coalesce(1).write(pathToDir)
```

the json would be in a file which looks something like this: part-00000-e3421247-f8cd-4ecb-b8e6-fc26894f5282.json

If you don't have spark defined (would be defined if you use pyspark shell or properly configured your notebook) which would be the case if you are running the code from an external script you would do something like:

```
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("example").getOrCreate()
```

to create it.

Comment: Hey , it's a silly question but are you importing this spark variable 'spark.read.json(pathToFile)' like this 'from pyspark.sql import SQLContext as spark' and Would you please write the code for the column 'a' , I need the sum operation on column 'a' while grouping 'b','c','d'columns

Comment: Added both. spark is the default name for spark session when generated using pyspark. I added an example of how to generate it but you should really check out the programming guide to do it properly for your case

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. The above code is working. Can you please suggest some good documentation that I can go through.:)

Comment: Hey , Just one last think .If I have a column say 'f' whose value is '0' or '1'.And if the value of the column is '1' then only these aggregation should perform , otherwise i want to drop that row in the first place.

Comment: Then just filter the dataframe before the aggregation. In the example above do df.filter(df["f"] == 1)